# Unity shows no icons or launcher,  I get only the wallpaper

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, desktop-background

When I log in using Unity all I get is the wallpaper - no icons, no launcher, no apps, nothing. I can only get ubuntu classic to work (GNOME as far as I know) because I'm new to Ubuntu and I only like Unity. I hope someone can help me to get it working.

Comment: Try `unity --replace` from the command line and see if that works..Also are you sure you installed unity correctly? and did you update correctly (post-installation)?

Answer (score 3):

you can reset the unity by running:

```
unity --reset
```

and

```
unity --reset-icons
```

i hope it be useful